# How to invest Rs.10k in India

Tags: investing, india, investment-strategies

I would like to invest my savings Rs.10,000 which gives me higher returns. I do not want to save in bank FDs. I would like to take some risk(yeah.. Rs.10000 is not a big amount) as the amount is not much higher. What are all the options do i got in India?

Comment: In percentages, what range of returns would be acceptable? What is your risk appetite? How much time do you have to devote to the process?

Answer (score 1):

Rs 10,000 is a small but good amount to begin with. I would suggest you start by investing in some good mutual funds. Do some research, a balance mutual fund is less risky less returns compared to a equity mutual fund.

The other option is directly investing in stock market, however this needs some experience and you would need to open demat and trading accounts that would cost money to open and maintain.

Comment: One can also look at alternative medium to high risk options such as corporate FDs and NCD (Non-convertible debentures for returns in the range of 10-15%. There are other high return options but that would involve opening trading accounts such as forex, F&O, stocks, commodities etc.

Comment: Goto http://fundsindia.com The MF portfolio recommended by them is usually good.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that this is going to be a long term investment and you don't need this money before 5-6years at the very least.

My advise would be to invest in one of the following funds :

IDFC Premier equity fund growth plan (Direct) (Only SIP allowed right now)

ICICI Discovery fund growth plan (Direct)

DSP microcap fund growth plan (Direct)

In case you do not want to be invested in small and mid cap and want a little less volatility then my first choice for that would be :

[Quantum long term equity fund dividend plan](http://www.investorforum.in/topic/6-quantum-long-term-equity-fund/)

Whatever you go for make sure you go directly with the fund house and not through a broker as you end up getting charged an extra .63% extra as opposed to going direct and you will also be paying for a demat account which can be avoided if you invest directly with a fund house. Out of the above mentioned funds Quantum has the lowest expense ratio of 1.25% and it is a huge benefit if you are talking 10+ years because it makes a lot of difference.

**Source : My own research and experience as an investor.**